# querydsl transformer group by count

Tags: java, sql, querydsl

I am stuck trying to get a query (QueryDSL) to work that gives me a count of distinct categories. 
For example, what I am trying to achieve:

```
categoryA -> 10 entries
categoryB -> 20 entries
```

This is what i have so far:

```
query().from(application)
            .transform(groupBy(application.category).as(list(application)));
```

However, this gives me for each category a list of all whole entries, I just want to get a count of this.

I tried messing around with `count()` but no luck.

Anybody know how to do this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

transform combined groupBy is meant to construct tree structures out of flat result sets. What you need can be easier expressed as

```
query.from(application)
     .groupBy(application.category)
     .list(application.category, application.category.count())
```

Answer (score 30):

Note that as of **Querydsl 4.x**, the accepted answer by Timo Westkämper is no longer valid. [Breaking changes in Querydsl 4.0 have removed the query.list() method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33103432/1399395).

A solution working with Querydsl 4.0+ would now be:

```
query.from(application)
     .groupBy(application.category)
     .select(application.category, application.category.count())
     .fetch();
```

Answer (score 5):

If using 4.1.4, you may need to use a **JPAQueryFactory** instead of **JPAQuery**

If using JPAQuery, there is no select() or fetch() on the return from groupBy.

```
JPAQueryFactory queryFactory = new JPAQueryFactory(entityManager);

queryFactory
     .select(application.category, application.category.count())
     .from(application)
     .groupBy(application.category)
     .fetch();
```

Answer (score 0):

In QueryDSL 4.4.0:

```
query.from(application)
   .groupBy(application.category)
   .transform(GroupBy.groupBy(application.category)).as(application.category.count()))
```

Learn more on: https://www.tabnine.com/code/java/methods/com.querydsl.jpa.JPQLQuery/transform