# Mysema Querydsl: There's no JPAQuery#list() method

Tags: maven, querydsl

Some online examples for **Mysema Querydsl** usage rely on the `JPAQuery#list()` method, e.g. [this stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26742755/1399395) containing a GROUP BY / COUNT aggregate example. It is also referred to throughout the [official documentation](http://www.querydsl.com/static/querydsl/latest/reference/html_single/).

However, I do just not see this method on the `JPAQuery` class. It doesn't show up in the IDE's autocomplete, and it's not present in the JAR file downloaded by Maven.

I have added these dependencies to my Maven project:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
    <artifactId>querydsl-apt</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.4</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
    <artifactId>querydsl-jpa</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.4</version>
</dependency>
```

Why is the `JPAQuery#list()` method not present?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The method `JPAQuery.list` was removed when Querydsl upgraded from the [3.x](http://www.querydsl.com/static/querydsl/3.6.8/apidocs/com/mysema/query/jpa/impl/JPAQuery.html) to the [4.x](http://www.querydsl.com/static/querydsl/4.0.0/apidocs/com/querydsl/jpa/impl/JPAQuery.html) line. Since you are using version 4.0.4, this method is no longer available.

As I understand from reading the [release notes](http://www.querydsl.com/releases), version 4 introduces a lot of major changes in the code base that breaks older code. You have two options:

- downgrade to the last version of the 3.x line, which 3.6.8 and use the `list` method
- keep version 4.0.4 and use the [`fetch`](http://www.querydsl.com/static/querydsl/4.0.4/apidocs/com/querydsl/core/Fetchable.html#fetch--) method instead. Take a look at [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/querydsl/querydsl/issues/1120) for the list of changes.

Comment: Thank you Tunaki. That's what I was afraid of. I think I'll try to stick with 4.0.4 and figure out how to upgrade my queries. @Mysema people: Would anyone mind updating the reference doc?

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. Will be fixed https://github.com/querydsl/querydsl/pull/1626

Comment: What about the list method that takes a parameter (in mysema). fetch() does not take any parameters.

Comment: @Tisha I think, it is `select(...).fetch()`, [see here for example](https://github.com/querydsl/querydsl/pull/1217/files#diff-7e7ef10caa3efd492957e81c151a23efL122).

Comment: Ok, I moved to com.querydsl package but even this doesn't seem to be working - jpaQuery.from(qGroup, qType, qCountry) --> <y Qclasses are of EntityPathBase type, where as the from method of JPAQuery expects EntityPath classes. Do I need to regenerate my QClasses with the new package?

Comment: @Tisha I'm afraid I don't know here, perhaps you should ask a separate question.