# Querydsl: The method list is undefined for the type QueryBase

Tags: spring-data-jpa, querydsl

I am trying to select specific column in `Querydsl` using `.list`. I am getting following error message at `.list()`

```
public List<Account> btnSearchClick(String sclientacctid, String sacctdesc, String sinvestigatorname,
            String sdeptname) {

        QAccount account = QAccount.account;
        QDepartment department = QDepartment.department;
        QAccountCPCMapping accountCPCMapping = QAccountCPCMapping.accountCPCMapping;
        QInvestigator investigator = QInvestigator.investigator;

        @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
        JPAQuery query = new JPAQuery(em);      
                  query
                       .from(account)
                       .innerJoin(account.department, department)
                       .innerJoin(account.accountCPC, accountCPCMapping)
                       .innerJoin(account.investigator, investigator)
                       .where(account.ninstid.eq(60))
                       .list(account.sclientacctid , department.sdeptname, investigator.sinvestigatorname , accountCPCMapping.sccpcode);
```

**Error message at .list()**

```
The method list(StringPath, StringPath, StringPath, StringPath) is undefined for the type QueryBase
```

Can any one tell me why Query not taking .list()?

Answer (score 1):

Which version of querydsl are you using? 
If major of 4.x that method is no longer available.
Try to modify your code this way:

```
QueryBase queryBase= new JPAQuery(em)....
FetchableQueryBase fetchable = (FetchableQueryBase) queryBase;
fetchable.fetch();
```

Or downgrade to querydsl 3.x to use list().

[click-here-for-info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33102742/mysema-querydsl-theres-no-jpaquerylist-method)